# IOS, openGLES draw at different Z

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos2d to create a basketball game. 
When the ball falls into the net, and I want to draw some line of the net behind the ball, and some line infront of the ball. How do you do this?

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile: @"ball.png"]; 
[self addChild: sprite z: 0]; 

-(void)draw
{
    [super draw];

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
    kmGLPushMatrix();

    glLineWidth(4.20f);
    ccDrawColor4B(220, 220, 220, 200);

    //Should draw behind 
    ccDrawLine(pos1, pos2);

    //Should draw infront
    ccDrawLine(pos2, pos3);



    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```

Comment: What about having the net separated in 2 different nodes, so you can put the ball sprite between them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use different CCLayers or you draw the lines on a CCRenderTexture.